# Android's listView placeholder for empty space

Tags: android, listview, placeholder

In my ListView i have this gray separator, and i want to have it as empty item on the ListView while i have only a few item. Actually, there is a background with the lines, but in this case if i modify the height of items, i have to recreate the background with photoshop. How to do it automatically? i can't keep it modified every time i modify the height on item, and a PNG background is smooth on Android.

[image]

The ListViews XML is:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/repolist"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end"
        android:background="@drawable/libreriasfondo"
        android:divider="#a6a6a6"
    android:clickable="false">

</ListView>
```

Comment: what's in liberiasfondo.jpg?, also make the height wrap content instead

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/libreriapattern"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:dither="true"/>` it's just the drawable of an empty item, repeated in all the listview to simulate the empty view.

Comment: It seems it cannot be automated. Bitmaps have the "repeat" property, but they don't have any kind of "distance between repeat" property. Though it can be emulated by generating a LinearLayout with gray lines and empty items, but it is much slower than using an image.